# Find the equation of curve through $(1,1)$ the slope of whose tangent line at $(x,y)$ is $y^{10}/x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**... Express you answer as y^-9 =**

I assume I need to set up a differential equation, but I do not even know where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the differential equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^{10}}{x^3}$$
with initial condition $y(1)=1$.
The variables can be separated, so solving the DE should not be difficult.

Why? Because the differential equation above says *exactly* that the slope of the tangent line at $(x,y)$, which is $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$, is equal to the expression on the right.

Comment: I got (-1/9)y^(-9)=(-1/2)x^(-2)+C

Comment: But it's not right.

Comment: NVM got it. Thanks!

Comment: You need to evaluate $C$ using the initial condition.